# Does there exist a singer's muzzle or silencer?

Tags: voice

I'd like to be able to sing full voice in the middle of the dead of night and when the other tenants are in the apartments and residences. Does there exist a singer's muzzle or silencer? Something which would quite my voice? ***I'm partially deaf so its important that I not expose myself to my voice at full strength all the time but still practice.***

Comment: In the car with the doors and windows closed ! You could even have backing tracks playing. In a garage is ideal, but you could always drive to a secluded spot. Might attract Police interest though...

Comment: @Tim You need a large car, though, since you probably want to be standing to sing at full voice.

Comment: To protect your hearing, earplugs or earmuffs should work. Or isolation headphones.

Comment: But which ones provide equal dampening of bass and treble cause everyone know about the resonance problem @ChristopherCreutzig

Comment: I am confused. If you are partially deaf, I understand the concern for your neighbors' peace and quiet since you may not be able to tell how loud you are, but I was not aware that any kind of partial deafness made your ears easier to damage. You should not be able to damage your own hearing with your own voice without any kind of amplification.

Comment: @NReilingh i do have amplification though...hearing aids..thats how i'm able to tune accuratly

Answer (score 9):

Well, a pillow.  The problem of most silencers, namely different response and resonances and sound characteristics is, of course, acerbated since the voice is very much driven by sensory and acoustic feedback.  So that is not a realistic solution.

More realistic would be a practice chamber, namely a sound-proofed cabin you build somewhere in your apartment.  Again, the acoustics are not really optimal for singing but way better than what you might expect with devices deserving the title "muzzle or silencer".

Comment: a silencer which provided feedback through a mike played through headphones would allow for sensory input?

Comment: And then the heat from your breath heats up the pillow and you need to find another solution ;)

Comment: I wonder if you could build a mini-practice-chamber by sound-proofing a medium size cardboard box, and putting it over your head?! You'd get the damping effect of the pillow but your voice wouldn't actually be muffled and you could even put a mic inside.

Answer (score 5):

Do a Google search on "vocal isolation booth" and you will find many companies that sell these devices. They the size of a walk-in closet, and they are expensive. But this is the only really effective option for an apartment.

Comment: uh but i want something to control my ears exposure too not just confine the sound to a region

Comment: If this is about your health and your hearing, you had better consult a physician, and not accept advice from a place like this.

Comment: A particularly advanced sound isolation room can actually provide variable virtual acoustics, so you can make it sound like you're in a large hall, or even act as a dampener so everything isn't coming right back at you.

Answer (score 5):

If you are concerned about a "muzzle or silencer" then you don't really understand how singing works, and you don't understand how your ears work either.

Anything that would "muzzle" the mouth or the voice would severely alter the way that you form words and sounds, and severely alter the way that you form the notes themselves. You would sing in a way that would ruin your singing technique because you could not form the notes and sounds correctly, you could not hear them correctly, and you would train yourself to sing wrong with the wrong technique. (not to mention that you would probably have a lot of trouble *breathing!*)

More importantly, [to the best of my knowledge as an experienced singer who is university-trained in singing and music, but who is not a healthcare professional] there **is no way** to "control my ears' exposure" to your own voice in your own head.

With regard to your hearing, when you hear the sound of your own voice when you sing or speak, your ears are picking up the sounds that come from within your body, through bone conduction within your skull, to a much greater degree than they are picking up sounds that come from outside your body through your outer ears. There is no way to muffle this or reduce its volume. So doing something to plug up your ears would not help with regard to hearing the sound of your own voice. This would be counterproductive as well.

Your question indicates that you don't really understand how singing works, and how singing affects hearing. Therefore I suggest that you get some singing lessons from a professional voice teacher. If necessary because of your hearing loss, perhaps you would  also need some therapy from a healthcare professional who works with people with hearing loss, or with speech therapy or vocal rehabilitation therapy. You need enough lessons with a professional to learn about how your singing voice works, and how to use it.

Singing well is all about learning to hear your own voice and learning to make pleasing sounds with pleasing vocal technique. In order to do this you have to sing freely with no restrictions, and you have to hear freely with no restrictions. Anything else and you will be producing ugly sounds, training yourself to become accustomed to ugly sounds, and removing your ability to tell the difference between ugly sounds and pleasing sounds being produced by your own voice. There is no point to that.

Comment: @caseyr547, I did not intend to diss you. I just think that if you are worried about singing with regard to your hearing impairment, you need to consult medical professionals. I don't think that anybody on this site has experience helping singers who are hearing-impaired. Please understand that I'm trying to point you in the right direction in the best way I know how.

Comment: it is just the same as if I was at a concert bud or in a studio it's not some great affliction I would go through each of the points you make but it's just way over react

Comment: i've had some lessons he said i was able to tune ok...my enunciations are not great...i have not been able to practice in a while...this is what i sound like right now https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=08kb8XlCvMY

Answer (score 4):

There are plenty of tricks. I guess the cheapest way to do this is to hang bed sheets on your walls, egg boxes or foam that is shaped like it. However, depending on how thick the walls are in your building, it will not be enough... These are the 3 most commonly used and cheapest solutions, but they are also the least effective...

Comment: Egg boxes are marginally useful for reducing reflections, and more-or-less-completely useless for sound-proofing. They are also extremely flammable.

Answer (score 0):

There is.  It's pretty cool, but I forget what it's called a belt box! It's a device you can buy that's shaped like an oxygen mask and makes a full on loud belt very very quiet. Made for practicing in apartments and at odd hours. Google "belt ya face off"